# How to interact with a javascript variable in python using wx.html2.Webview in wxPython

Tags: javascript, python, html, wxpython, monaco-editor

It seems I have a very easy problem to solve but with my little experience working with web technologies I'll be more than grateful if someone bring some light in this darkness.

I am testing the Monaco Editor ([Monaco WebDocu](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.44.0#example-creating-the-editor-hello-world)) using a wx.html2.WebView ([wx.html2 Doku](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.html2.WebView.html#wx.html2.WebView.EnableAccessToDevTools)) in wxPython. The load of the "index.html" and the preliminary scripts work like a charm. The problem begin when I try to modify a created variable in a script loaded initially from the html when it loads directly from python. (See html below)

```html
    <html> 
        <head> 
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" 
                  data-name="vs/editor/editor.main" 
                  href="./min/vs/editor/editor.main.css" /> 
            <style> 
                html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; } 
                #container { height: 100%; } 
            </style> 
        </head>
        <body> 
            <div id="container"></div> 
            <script src="./min/vs/loader.js"></script> 
            <script> 
                require.config({ paths: { 'vs': './min/vs' } }); 
            </script> 
            <script src="./min/vs/editor/editor.main.nls.js"></script> 
            <script src="./min/vs/editor/editor.main.js"></script> 
            <script> 
                var code_editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), { 
                    value: '#Some comment',
                    language: 'python',
                    theme: 'vs-dark'
                }); 
            </script> 
        </body> 
    </html>
```

From the index.html I am invoking the a javascript containing a variable called code_editor.
Now on my Python code I´ve tried the lines commented to reach the code-editor variable like this:

```py
import wx 
import wx.html2 

class Editor(wx.Dialog): 
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwds): 
    wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwds) 
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
    self.editor = wx.html2.WebView.New(self) 
    self.editor.EnableAccessToDevTools(enable=True)
    sizer.Add(self.editor, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10) 
    self.SetSizer(sizer) 
    self.SetSize((700, 700)) 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  app = wx.App() 
  dialog = Editor(None, -1)
  dialog.editor.LoadURL(r'C:\Users\JuergenK\Documents\Monaco\index.html')
  
  # TEST SECTION WITH RETRIEVING VAR EDITOR
  # Try 1: NOT WORKING
  dialog.editor.RunScript("code_editor.getModel().setValue('import pywhatever1');")
  # Try 2: NOT WORKING
  dialog.editor.AddUserScript("code_editor.getModel().setValue('import pywhatever2');")
  # Try 3: NOT WORKING
  dialog.editor.RunScriptAsync("code_editor.getModel().setValue('import pywhatever3');")

  dialog.Show() 
  app.MainLoop()
```

Does someone know how to reach successfully the code_editor variable in python?.

**PS:** By the way, I used the Development Tools from M.Edge, and the Javascript code that I am intending to pass and it is working properly!.

**Environment:**
OS: Windows 10
Browser: M. Edge
Python: 3.10.10
wx: 4.2.1 msw (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.2.2.1

Thank you in advance!